# How to print line segment on a particular printer in python?

Tags: python

I'm doing some test for a program. So basically what im trying to do is to send to a printer some lines like "---" but i can't draw them. I don't know how.

I've tried all of those libraries like mathplotlib but it doesn't help because for me to send the info to the printer i have to send a string.

```
import tempfile
import win32api
import win32print
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filename = tempfile.mktemp (".txt")

line = plt.plot((0, 24), (-10, -10), linestyle='--', color='red')

open (filename, "w").write(line)

win32api.ShellExecute (
  0,
  "print",
  filename,
  '/d:"%s"' % win32print.GetDefaultPrinter (),
  ".",
  0
)
```

Comment: Why are you using matplotlib to write plaintext to a printer?

Comment: Because I'm trying to draw lines and send them to a printer. I was searching for to do that and I found matplotlib. I know that what I did doesn't work.

Comment: Do you *have* to use text to communicate with the printer?

Comment: Well that's the code I found to communicate to the printer. If you have any other idea of how to communicate to the printer and send the lines to it I would be grateful.